# Crontab as other user

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab, cronjob

I am running crontab as root user:

```
screen -S konsola -X stuff 'say hello'`echo -ne '\015'`
```

How do I run it as the user "nobody"? Only this user has screen with given pid, thats why I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use `crontab -u nobody -e` to add your command to nobody's crontab?

Otherwise I would just put this in the root crontab:

```
su nobody -c "screen -S konsola -X stuff 'say hello'`echo -ne '\015'`"
```

From the man page:

```
The su command is used to become another user during a login session.
[...]
 -c, --command  COMMAND
    Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its -c.
```

Comment: nobody user cant do cronjobs/tab - hes not privillaged to. what `crontab -u nobody -e` does?

Comment: It edits the crontab file of user nobody

Comment: As I said `nobody` user cant run crontab. Is there a way to let him run it only for one *.sh?